# SASS import a file without nesting

Tags: css, sass, preprocessor

I need to combine an SCSS file into a namespace but I don't want to modify the file directly.

Assume, we have "book.scss" that contains

```
.book {
   color: red;
}
```

if I want to import the file into a namespace using

```
.context {
    @import 'book';
}
```

This will produce a nested selector

```
.context .book {
    color: red;
}
```

However, I want it in this way. Notice there is no space between context and book

```
.context.book {
    color: red;
}
```

Is this possible with SASS?

Comment: I know you don't want to modify the file. But there is no way as omukiguy wrote. But when you set an `&` at the beginning of your book.scss, you will get the correct result: `&.book { color: red; }`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way. You will just have to import the file and then extend the class

```
.context.book {
    @extend .book;
}
```